# Is there such a thing? Wall access panel with a water shutoff -> so I can turn off water to outside spigot in the winter?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

Im looking to see if such thing exists.

Nice looking wall access panel with a shutoff ball valve inside -> so I can turn off water to outside spigot in the winter?

Comment: Probably as two separate parts that you combine - an access panel, and a ball valve.

Comment: If you're worried about your line freezing, [this](https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.non-freeze-wall-hydrant-anti-siphon-12-inch-male--x-12-inch-solder-8-inch.1000135892.html) may be a better alternative.

Comment: @Chris Yeah - I can't use that - it's too long and will go all the way into the house through the drywall.

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do.  Put the valve inside the heated area of your home.  And also auto-drain the pipe downstream of the valve.  You will need to do that somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You want to install a freeze-, frost-proof silcock. That will allow you to turn the water off from outside, while eliminating water sitting outside the conditioned space of the home.

[image]

They are available in many different lengths, so they fit most applications.

Comment: Yeah - I can't use that - it's too long and will go all the way into the house through the drywall.

Comment: @Dannyboy have you tried searching the internet using the term "*plumbing access panel*"? How does the plumbing get into the wall? Why can't you put a valve where the plumbing enters the wall?

Comment: hmm. now that I've google it - yes I see they are available.